# iphone sleeps in recovery mode

Tags: iphone, itunes, jailbreak, sleep-wake, ios

i am trying to restore 4.3.1 custom firmware made by sn0wbrzee with expert mode.

at the last moment of restore itunes shows 1015 error. so i try to reboot, but iphone not rebooted.

at last I jailbrak with redsnow and iphone rebotted and i see my firmware was 4.3.1 with bb 6.15.00, but after 10 mints it sleep forever.

after this situation i tried for hours and hours by various method.but no result i get.
and now when i try restore it by itune during recovery mode, i tune shows 1601 error during the step " preparing iphone for restore "

please help. i become hopeless. also please say can i get back my lovely i phone, or i lost forever this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help resolve the error 1015:

http://iphonerumors.blogspot.com/2010/11/bypassing-itunes-1004-1015-error-when.html