# Restoring a jailbroken iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, restore, error

I'm trying to restore a iPhone 3g I got that was jailbroken. I plugged it into itunes and hit restore and received the error 1015 that it could not be restored. I've tried using the tinyumbrella solution I believe I did it correctly but it did not work. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What version of iOS?

Comment: Near duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/iphone-sleeps-in-recovery-mode/13020#13020

Comment: Are you trying to restore to a certain firmware? You may need to upgrade to the latest version your device supports. (4.2.1, I believe)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put it in DFU mode before restoring...

This can be done by:

1. Open iTunes and connect the iPhone to your Mac or PC.
2. Press and hold the Home button and the Sleep/Wake button at the same time. After
   exactly 10 seconds release the Sleep/Wake button. Continue holding
   the home button until you iTunes pops up a message telling you that
   it has detected an iPhone in recovery mode.
3. The iPhone screen will remain black.

NOTE***: It may take a few attempts to get your iPhone into DFU mode. Generally, I hold down both buttons then release the Home button just before I think the Apple logo would appear. If you are still holding both buttons down and you see the Apple logo you are holding them down for too long!